# Calling a decorated function twice returns only the decorator and not the function

Tags: python-3.x, python-decorators

> Here is my code that defines the timed decorator:

```
from functools import wraps, lru_cache

def timed(fn):
    from time import perf_counter

    @wraps(fn)
    def inner(*args,**kwargs):
        start = perf_counter()
        result = fn(*args,**kwargs)
        end = perf_counter()
        timer = end - start

        fs = '{} took {:.3f} microseconds'
        print(fs.format(fn.__name__, (end - start) * 1000000))

        return result
    return inner
```

> Here is the function definition:

```
@timed
@lru_cache
def factorial(n):
    result = 1
    cache = dict()
    if n < 2:
        print('Calculating factorial for n > 1')

        result = 1
        print(f'factorial of {result} is {result}')

    else:
        for i in range(1,n+1):
            if i in cache.items():
                result = cache[i]
                #print(f'factorial of {i} is {result}')
            else:
                result *= i
                cache[i] = result

        print(f'factorial of {i} is {result}')
            #print(f'{cache}')
    return result
```

---

> Here are the calls to the functions:

factorial(3)

factorial(10)

factorial(10)

> Here is the output

```
factorial of 3 is 6
factorial took 32.968 microseconds
factorial of 10 is 3628800
factorial took 11.371 microseconds
**factorial took 0.323 microseconds**
```

> Question:
>   Why when I call factorial(10) the second time, there is no Print out?

Comment: Why are you using `lru_cache` *and* maintaining your own cache?

Comment: I should take it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only want to cache *pure* functions; your factorial isn't pure, because it has a side effect of writing to standard output.

For the behavior you want, define two functions: a pure function that you cache, and an impure wrapper that uses the pure function.

```
@lru_cache
def factorial_math(n):
    result = 1
    for i in range(2, n):
        result *= i
    return result

@timed
def factorial(n):
    result = factorial_math(n)
    print(f'factorial of {n} is {result}')
    return result
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the whole point of `lru_cache` is to cache the function's arguments and the return values associated with them and to *minimize the number of actual executions of the decorated function*.

When you call `factorial(10)` *for the second time*, the function isn't called, but rather the value is fetched from the cache. And this is also why the second call is *35 times faster* - because the function isn't even called, and that's the exact purpose of `functools.lru_cache`.